# flink consumes rabbitmq messages in parallel, how to ensure sequential consumption

Tags: apache-flink

I listen to mysql binlog through flink, then drop it to rabbitmq queue, consume rabbitmq messages in flink, set parallelism to 1 for sequential consumption of messages, but this will cause flink task oom, is there any way to support multiple parallelism and consume sequentially? Please advise, thanks!

Comment: What are you doing in your Flink job that needs so much memory? Did you increase the default memory settings to match your machine? Ideally, you set only that part of your pipeline to parallelism of 1 that needs the sequential order and fan out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description of the problem, It seems like you want to use multiple event sources and process them sequentially.

But it depends on what order that sequence is in.

You may check the concept of time semantics in flink.

If you can define event time for each event sent from multiple parallel sources, you can use Event Time Semantics together with AssignedWatermark.
So that when flink received them, it knows to process them in event time order regardless of the time flink receive them ( which is processing time).

Keywords are: ***Event Time*** (which is the default) and ***Processing Time***